# The velocity of an object leaving the inclined plane

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, kinematics

I saw the question below in our physics textbook. It asks

> A block of mass m is released  and  slides down  on the frictionless inclined surface ( the inclined plane is of  concrete and doesn't move).  How long does the object take to reach the point M. (All surfaces are frictionless.)

[image]

The answer is

$$\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{\frac{2h}{g\sin^2{\theta}}}$$

The solution assumes that the velocity at $M$ ($v_M$) is the same as at $L$ ($v_L$).  But in my solution, the velocity through $LM$ should be $v\cos{\theta}$,  not $v$. And my solution is not correct and it violates  the mechanical energy conservation at points  $K$ and $M$. But I think that the normal force at point L will do work on the block, which  will be equal to the kinetic energy corresponding to $v\sin{\theta}$, which will substantiate my solution.

Answer (score 0):

The textbook that you referred probably ignored the collision with the ground. Or in other words, it assumes that the block will seamlessly change its direction at point $M$.

As for, "But I think that the normal force at point $L$ will do work on the block, which will be equal to the kinetic energy corresponding to $vsinθ$", I do not agree.

Normal forces do not do work. So where is the energy lost then? The heat and sound generated when the block goes ***THWAK!!*** on the floor of course.